# css stylus escaped characters

Tags: css-selectors, stylus

**[CHECK OUT CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/ncawthon/pen/epLLqa?editors=110)**

In stylus, trying to figure out why the usage of a variable within loop is throwing off the recognition of the 'background' as a css selector:

```
 $primary = rgba(255,0,0,1)
 $primary-light = lighten($primary,15%)
 $primary-lighter = lighten($primary,40%)
 $primary-lightest = lighten($primary,65%)
 $primary-dark = darken($primary,15%)
 $primary-darker = darken($primary,40%)
 $primary-darkest = darken($primary,65%)

 for colors in primary
  for vars in light lighter lightest dark darker darkest
    .{colors} > .{vars}
      background {colors}-{vars} /* here why not triggering */
      &:after
        content \"@background\"
```

HTML

```
 <body>
       <div class="primary">
         <div class="lightest"></div>
         <div class="lighter"></div>
         <div class="light"></div>
         <div class="dark"></div>
         <div class="darker"></div>
         <div class="darkest"></div>
       </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently use interpolation for variable names, but you can use [lookup](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#lookupname) bif here:

```
$primary = rgba(255,0,0,1)
$primary-light = lighten($primary,15%)
$primary-lighter = lighten($primary,40%)
$primary-lightest = lighten($primary,65%)
$primary-dark = darken($primary,15%)
$primary-darker = darken($primary,40%)
$primary-darkest = darken($primary,65%)

for colors in primary
  for vars in 'light' 'lighter' 'lightest' 'dark' 'darker' 'darkest'
    .{colors} > .{vars}
      background lookup('$' + colors + '-' + vars) // just build variable name from other vars values (don't forget about $ sign)
      &:after
        content \"@background\"
```

Also you should probably use strings for the keys otherwise `light` and `dark` would be treated as built-in functions (they're already defined).

I guess you can also look at [hashes](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/hashes.html), imho they're better suitable for this task.